# Use existing string as valueForKey value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use a string ("levelNumberString") as a valueForKey in an NSDictionary. When I use a string like `@"1"`, it all works perfectly, but when I decide to swap out that kind of string for `levelNumberString`, it gives me a SIGABRT error. The integer `levelInt` is an integer that decides what level the app is at. When the view is loaded, it is worth 1, and its value is taken up by the "levelNumberString" string.

This is my code (it's in viewDidLoad, if that helps at all):

```
NSString *levelNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i%", levelInt];
NSDictionary *packDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[rootDict valueForKey:levelNumberString]];
```

The above code is what is giving me the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it should be %i in the [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i%", levelInt];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is over here **@"i%"** it should be **@"%i"**

```
NSString *levelNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", levelInt];
NSDictionary *packDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[rootDict valueForKey:levelNumberString]];
```

Comment: I wonder if that would cause the SIGBRT.  levelNumberString is still a string with "i" in it.   I guess the [rootDict valueForKey:levelNumberString] would return nil because the key is wrong and [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:nil] will crash with SIGABRT error.  Does that make sense? Thanks!